# How to override the core function format_xml_elements()?

Tags: 7, hooks

`format_xml_elements()` is defined in the core includes/common.inc file. I want to manipulate some parts of this code, but there is no way to hook into this.

How could I achieve this without hacking core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly make Drupal use a different function instead of `format_xml_elements()`, but you can replace those functions that (directly or not) calls `format_xml_elements()`.
For example, to alter how the RSS page for a feed is printed, you just need to replace [`theme_aggregator_page_rss()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21aggregator%21aggregator.pages.inc/function/theme_aggregator_page_rss/7.x) with a function implemented from your module using [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7.x); to alter the output for the 'blog/%user/feed, or the blog/feed, or the taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/feed, you implement [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x) to replace the page callback Drupal uses with your own page callback.

What changes is the code you need to write in each case.
For example, [`taxonomy_term_feed()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.pages.inc/function/taxonomy_term_feed/7.x), the page callback for taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/feed, calls [`node_feed()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_feed/7.x), which calls [`format_rss_item()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_rss_item/7.x), which calls [`format_xml_elements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_xml_elements/7.x). In this case, you can use the same code `taxonomy_term_feed()` uses, except it calls another function (e.g. `mymodule_node_fee()`) instead of `node_feed()`, which has the same code, except it doesn't call `format_rss_item()` nor `format_rss_channel()`, but your own functions. For the latter two functions, you can use the same code they use, except your code will code your replacement for `format_xml_elements()` instead of `format_xml_elements()`.

In the case of replacing `theme_aggregator_page_rss()`, you write less code.

Comment: For one of my custom feeds, I need to remove check_plain() function as its escaping a section of my feed output which I don't want.

Comment: @Patoshi it depends on how you created those custom feeds, and which path do they have. Without more details, I can just give the answer I have already given.